How to display the raw html response from API in react-data-table-component
I have to display the raw HTML in the react-data-table-component. I have raw HTML which is coming from API, now I want to display that HTML in react-data-table-component.
 const columns = [
        { name: 'status', selector: row => row.status}
 ];

const [list, setList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
   try {
     const response = await axios.get(route('users.get-users-list')); // Your API endpoint
         setList(response.data);
     } catch (err) {
         setError(err);
     } finally {
         setLoading(false);
     }
   };
   fetchData();
}, []);

<DataTable
   columns={columns}
   data={list}
   pagination
/>

The HTML appears literally rather than as HTML:

I need to display the html in react-data-table-component how to do that

You can try format and dangerouslySetInnerHTML
  {
    name: "status",
    selector: (row) => row.status,
    format: (row) => (
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: row.status }}></span>
    ),
  },

